# im having trouble figuring out how this nested functions get the values. can someone pls explain it to me. the code works btw

Tags: python, function, nested

im having trouble figuring out how this works. can someone pls explain it to me. the code works btw.

def foo(x, y):

```
def goo(x, y):

    x = 2*x

    y = 3*y

    z = x+y

    print('x =', x, '; y =', y, '; z =', z)

    return z


def hoo(x, y):

    x = x//2

    y = y//3

    z = x+y

    print('x =', x, '; y =', y, '; z =', z)

    return z


z = hoo(x,y) + goo(y,x)

print('x =', x, '; y =', y, '; z =', z)

return z


x = 10

y = 20

z = 30

print('x =', x, '; y =', y, '; z =', z)

z = foo(x,y)

print('x =', x, '; y =', y, '; z =', z)
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and read these guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To understand how a code works, just follow the functions.

`foo` is called. Since `integer` types are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)  ([wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objet_immuable)) in `foo(x,y)` `x` and `y` are copies of the `x` and `y` you gave as parameters.

In python expression are evaluated from left to right therefore.

First function `hoo` is called (same remark about parameters) the value of `x` and `y` are changed and `z` is computed you get `('x =', 5, '; y =', 6, '; z =', 11)` and  the value `z` (11) is returned.

Once outside `hoo` function `x` and `y` at this level are respectively 10 and 20 because they were not changed (immutable thing… see above) . Then function `goo` is called.  (same remark about parameters) (*warning* you enter `y` for parameter `x` of `goo` and `x` for parameter `y` of `goo`) the value of `x` and `y` are changed and `z` is computed you get ('x =', 40, '; y =', 30, '; z =', 70) and  the value `z` (70) is returned.

Once outside `goo` function `x` and `y` at this level are respectively 10 and 20 because they were not changed (immutable thing… see above).

The sum function between the two values returned by `hoo` and `goo` is done. `z`= 11 + 70. you get ('x =', 10, '; y =', 20, '; z =', 81) and z is returned.

Then outside `foo` function. `x` and `y` at this level are respectively 10 and 20 because they were not changed (immutable thing… see above) . z is given the value of the return function `foo` therefore `z`=81

And you get ('x =', 10, '; y =', 20, '; z =', 81)